# Use ng-click to show the right article using ng-show and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

The following happens in the **same controller**.

I have a page that shows a list of article titles. If the user clicks on an article title a popup will show the article in detail.

The **article titles** are generated by a ng-repeat.

```
<div class="adItem" ng-click="showArticle = tiki._id" ng-repeat="tiki in tikis track by tiki._id">
```

The **article details** are also generated by a ng-repeat:

```
<article class="adArticle" ng-show="showArticle === tiki._id" ng-repeat="tiki in tikis track by tiki._id">
```

Notice i'm using `ng-click` and `ng-show` with the variable '`showArticle`' to toggle the visibility of the article detail. If showArticle === the id of the article title, show the article detail.

However, this doesn't work, what am i doing wrong?

thx,

Kevin,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ng-repeat creates scope for each repeated element, say:

```
contoller-scope
child scope1
child scope2
```

`showArticle = tiki._id` sets child scope's variable, not controller-scope's.
Thats why u cant address it.

You should put it into function:  `ng-click="setSelected(tiki)"`

```
$scope.setSelected = function(tiki) {
  $scope.showArticle = tiki._id;
}
```

Then this will work.

Or you can `ng-click="$parent.showArticle = tiki._id"`. (This is bad style, but will still work)

However, this is bad way -- you dont need second repeat, just use object, not id:

```
$scope.setSelected = function(tiki) {
  $scope.showArticle = tiki;
}
```

and add it to output.